# Python error expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PngImageFile

Tags: python, telegram-bot

i'm trying to create a script in python that download a photo from an url and send it to a telegram bot. This is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

bot = telepot.Bot('***')
chat_id = ****

url='https://api.blockchain.info/charts/preview/market-price.png?timespan=30days&h=810&w=1440'

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo=open(img, 'rb'))
```

the error returned is: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PngImageFile

The picture is stored succesfully into img, the error is in bot.sendPhoto line.

Where is the mistake? I accept also a different way to do it. Thank you!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-75-8b821a935f08>     
in <module> ----> 1 bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo=open(img, 'rb'))

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PngImageFile
```

Comment: What did you expect that `open(img, 'rb')` was doing? It opens a file with the given name, but `img` is no filename.

Comment: Did you try just passing `img` directly to `sendPhoto`? What does the documentation of `sendPhoto` say about what it expects as `photo` argument?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @mkrieger1 passing img the error is AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'. Telegram documentation says that for photo parameter: Photo to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet, or upload a local photo by passing a file path

Comment: Did you try the second option, to simply pass the URL to the image?

Comment: yes, it works :) sorry i had to read this before

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to pass the path directory to the image as an argument instead of a PngImageFile object (img)? Otherwise, try to cast img to a bytes object.

Comment: There is no path to an image file, the image data comes from an HTTP request.